Problem with running BackgroundService in ASP.NET Core
I'm using ASP.NET Core and SignalR to develop a simple game. I ran into some problems while Adding a background service to manage the queue status and print the number of users in queue. I have this code so far:
using LOOM.Data;
using LOOM.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace LOOM.Models
{
    public class Cardinal : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<QueueHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

        public Cardinal(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IHubContext<QueueHub> queueHub)
        {
            _hubContext = queueHub;
            _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    var queueCount = QueueModel.GetQueueCount();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Queue Count: {queueCount}");
                    await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", queueCount.ToString());

                    if (queueCount > 2)
                    {
                        var player1 = QueueModel.Dequeue();
                        var player2 = QueueModel.Dequeue();
                        await CreateMatch(player1, player2);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error logging queue count: {ex.Message}");
                }

                // Wait for 1 second before sending the next message
                await Task.Delay(10000);
            }
        }

        internal async Task StartAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private async Task CreateMatch(QueueModel player1, QueueModel player2)
        {
            var matchGroup = $"{player1.Token}{player2.Token}";
            await _hubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(player1.ConnectionString, matchGroup);
            await _hubContext.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(player2.ConnectionString, matchGroup);
            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(matchGroup).SendAsync("StartMatch", $"{matchGroup}");

            Contest Contest = new Contest
            {
                GeneratedMatchId = matchGroup,
                PlayerOneToken = player1.Token,
                PlayerTwoToken = player2.Token,
                WinnerToken = player1.Token
            };

            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    var _DbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LoomDBContext>();
                    _DbContext.Contests.Add(Contest);
                    _DbContext.SaveChanges();
                    await _hubContext.Clients.Group(matchGroup).SendAsync("ReceiveQuestion", _DbContext.Questions.ToList());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm using a singleton to add this to my program.cs. But I can't get this code running. Nothing gets printed on the Console.
Here is my Program.cs:
using LOOM.Data;
using LOOM.Hubs;
using LOOM.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddSingleton<Cardinal>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<LoomDBContext>(option =>
{
    option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultSQLConnection"));
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<QueueHub>("/queueHub");

var Cardinal = app.Services.GetRequiredService<Cardinal>();

app.Run();


Your code is suffering from following wrong practices, having bugs and is in dire need of reworking, not only as in scope of the hosted service, but design as well. If you want to create a game server, you should not use hosted service, as it is based on a loop, resulting in unnecessary delay. You'll need a live and persistent connection capable of instant processing of incoming messages, so you should steer more into SignalR hubs.

Please read more about SinglaR and hosted service.

To properly register your background service in ASP.NET Core, replace this line in your Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Cardinal>(); 

...with this:
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Cardinal>(); 

Note: After making this change, you'll need to implement the StartAsync method in your Cardinal class. This is an essential part of the BackgroundService contract, and the lack of its implementation will result in a NotImplementedException.
